# Menú desplegable devuelve none cuando selecciono un valor

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, dash

Intento obtener el resultado de `Input('demo-dropdown', 'selection')` pero la seleccion me devuelve `None`. En efecto, en app.py construi el mio dropdown en `app.py`:

```
import dash_daq as daq
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import datetime as dt

from .server import app, server
from .callbacks import (search)

def article_search():
    return html.Div(
        [
            # Value we searc in the text
            html.Div(dcc.Input(id='input-box', type='text')),
            # Dropdown
            html.Div([
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='demo-dropdown',
                    options=[
                        {'label': 'khazaradze', 'value': 'khazaradze'},
                        {'label': 'gakharia', 'value': 'gakharia'}
                    ],
                    value='khazaradze'
                ),
                html.Div(id='dd-output-container')
            ]),
            # Date picker, to be change to a range selector
            html.Div([
                dcc.DatePickerRange(
                    id='my-date-picker-range',
                    min_date_allowed=dt.datetime(1995, 8, 5),
                    max_date_allowed=dt.datetime.today(),
                    initial_visible_month=dt.datetime(2017, 8, 5),
                    end_date=dt.datetime.today()
                ),
                html.Div(id='output-container-date-picker-range')
            ]),
            html.Button('Submit', id='button'),
            html.Div(id='output-container-button',
                     children='Enter a value and press submit'),
            html.H6(
                id='articles',
                children='Matching articles',
            )
        ]
    )

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        # empty Div to trigger javascript file for graph resizing
        html.Div(id="output-clientside"),
        # Header
        header(),
        dcc.Tabs(
            [

                dcc.Tab(
                    label='Search article',
                    value='search',
                    children=article_search()
                )
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

Se parece a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el call back en `search.py`:

```
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import datetime as dt

import pickle

from ..server import app

@app.callback(
    # Output('output-container-button', 'children'),
    Output('articles', 'children'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks'), 
    Input('my-date-picker-range', 'start_date'),
    Input('my-date-picker-range', 'end_date'),
    Input('demo-dropdown', 'selection')], # returns None ?
    [State('input-box', 'word')])
def update_search(n_clicks, start_date, end_date, word, selection):
    print(selection)
```

Pero esto me devuelve `None` cuando hago un clic sobre `Submit`.

Ahora `State('input-box', 'word')` tambien me devuelve `None`.

Comment: No veo una etiqueta **form** que envuelva a tu formulario search. Por eso el submit no funciona. Me imagino que ningún campo input te regresa un valor.

Answer (score 0):

> Argumentos de `dashcorecomponents.Input()`:
>
> - `id` (cadena; opcional): El ID de este componente, usado para identificar los componentes del guión en las llamadas de retorno. La
>     identificación tiene que ser única en todos los componentes en una
>     aplicación.
> - `value` (cadena | número; opcional): El valor de la entrada
> - ...

Pensaba que `value` fue el nombre de la valor que nos gustarian utilizar en el script y que el `id` fue sufficiente. Lejos de eso, es la valor del componente html que nos gustaria utilisar.

Entonces con `app.py` se necesita escribir:

```
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import datetime as dt

import pickle

from ..server import app

@app.callback(
    # Output('output-container-button', 'children'),
    Output('articles', 'children'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks'), 
    Input('my-date-picker-range', 'start_date'),
    Input('my-date-picker-range', 'end_date'),
    Input('demo-dropdown', 'value')], # returns None ?
    [State('input-box', 'value')])
def update_search(n_clicks, start_date, end_date, word, selection):
    print(selection)
```